# last_day in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

The oracle `last_day` function return the last day of the month.
example:

```
nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS'
select last_day(sysdate) from dual;
LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)
-------------------
2014-06-30 15:45:43
```

oracle return the time value as well.

I have tried below sql in PostgreSQL which return the last day of month but time value is "00:00:00".

```
select (date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month -1 day')::timestamp(0);
         ?column?          
---------------------------
 2014-06-30 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

the sql return the date correctly but I want date and time like oracle.

Comment: Actually, I think the fact that Oracle's `last_day` keeps the time portion should be considered a bug. It just doesn't fit in the domain of that kind of function. I didn't even know about it and probably anyone who uses it should go back and enclose the result in a `trunc` to get a "clean" value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select (
    date_trunc('month', now())
    + interval '1 month -1 day'
    + now()::time
)::timestamp(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function last_day() should do the trick. This function should be found in a extenstion package called "orafce". Containing other functions used in Oracle.

1. Install the correct version of orafce package (if needed):

   ```
   apt-get install postgresql-9.1-orafce
   ```
2. SQL:

   ```
   Create Extension orafce
   ```
3. If error rename orafce--3.0.sql to orafce--3.03.sql or user later version of orafce.
4. Use the function:

   ```
   SELECT last_day('2015-01-01')
   ```

Works like expected and the result is '2015-01-31'